# One identity about Eisenstein series and L functions of modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, l-functions

Currently, I'm reading Zagier's notes 'Modular forms whose Fourier coefficients involve zeta-function of quadratic fields'. There is an equation (72) in page 42:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma_{r}(n) a(n)}{n^s}=\frac{L_{f}(s) L_{f}(s-r)}{\zeta(2 s-r-k+1)} \quad\left(\operatorname{Re}(s)>r+\frac{k+1}{2}\right).$$
But I don't how to prove it and also didn't find its proof in the note. How can we prove it? Are there some references and suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: Did you try comparing Dirichlet series coefficients?

Comment: Ignoring the possibility that bad primes exist, you can show this via an extremely tedious computation comparing Euler products. I don't know a better way.

Comment: There is an elegant proof in Lemma 1.6.1 of "Automorphic Forms and Representations" by Daniel Bump.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kimball! I got the proof in the case of full level taking the action of Hecke operators into consideration following your suggestions.

Comment: Dear David, if we ignore the bad  primes from the level, how can we deal with those index $n$ not being coprime to the level?  Does it possible to get similar identities excluding those index $n$ not being coprime to the level?

Comment: Dear Humphries,  I tried your method. I think you mean that we view the left side as the Rankin-Selberg L-function of Eisenstein series and $f$. But I don't know how to show the right side of (6.25) is the same as the right side of the identity here. Would you mind give me more suggestions or references?

Comment: @Strange I believe Peter is referring to Lemma 1.6.1, and you're referring to Theorem 1.6.1 (and in the book Lemma 1.6.1 appears a few pages after Theorem 1.6.1). The Lemma does much of the gruntwork for a comparison of Euler products.